# Why the app freezes when selecting a file?

Tags: java, android, file, wifi, p2p

I'm writing an application where the function of transferring files between phones via WiFi P2P should be implemented. My phones see each other and connect correctly, but when I select a file in the file manager, the phone just freezes and nothing happens, it doesn’t write any errors in the logcat, or in the console in general. All permissions for the application are registered. What could be the problem?
I am attaching the code that describes the method for sending the file
`your text`

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });
```

```
private void sendFile(Uri fileUri, HostInfo info) {
        checkPermission();
           String hostAddress = null;
        if (info!= null && info.groupOwnerAddress != null){
            hostAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;
        }
        if (hostAddress == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Host adress is null");
            return;
        }
            int port = 0;
            int buffersize = 1024;
        try(Socket socket = new Socket()) {
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, socket.getLocalPort()), 5000);
            checkPermission();
            //  try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

           try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()){
               File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                byte[] nameBuffer = file.getName().getBytes();
                outputStream.write(nameBuffer.length);
                outputStream.write(nameBuffer, 0, nameBuffer.length);
                System.out.println(file.getPath());
                long fileSize = file.length();
                outputStream.write((byte) ((fileSize >> 24) & 0xFF));
                outputStream.write((byte) ((fileSize >> 16) & 0xFF));
                outputStream.write((byte) ((fileSize >> 8) & 0xFF));
                outputStream.write((byte) (fileSize & 0xFF));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                socket.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            HostInfo info = new HostInfo();
            info.groupOwnerAddress = "192.168.49.1";
            sendFile(selectedFileUri, info);

        }
    }
```

At first there was a problem that when selecting a file it would display No such file or directory, but by slightly correcting the code I got rid of this error, but now the phone just freezes

Comment: could you start the debugger and go line by line, to see where it freezes ?

Comment: You are likely getting an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` - search on this term in [android] and should get some solutions.  You should inspect your logcat to verify this exception trace since you do not handle it and the activity will stop and display this information.

Comment: `All permissions for the application are registered.` You do not need any permission to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: We do not believe that your app freezes when the user has not yet selected a file.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `sendFile(selectedFileUri, info);`

method in background-thread/AsyncTask

or else the file read & write operation will block the main thread result in UI/APP freezes.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: this sure is the answer here.